# Вывод даты из datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Не могу вывести дату из `datetime`. `print` печатает время с датой, хотя в Pandas-таблице время не отображается.

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
print (today)
print( today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") )
```

Результат:

```
2020-09-23 00:15:59.418511
09/23/2020
```

А вообще такие вопросы гууглятся самостоятельно за 15 секунд.  А ответ на форуме ожидается часами. Логику понять трудно.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, в вашем случае это будет выглядеть так

```
print(allData['dDate'][1].date())
```

Если тип столбца datetime.datetime